# C# Dictionary, 2 Values

Tags: c#, dictionary

What would be the best C# data structure for using one key, and having two values pulled out?

Essentially I need a `Dictionary<string, string, string>`. Is there something like this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you're using .NET 4, you could use

```
Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>>
```

If you're not, you could create your own `Tuple` type which works the same way :)

Alternatively, if you only need this in one place you could create your own type which encapsulated the two strings neatly using appropriate names. For example:

```
public sealed class NameAndAddress
{
    private readonly string name;
    public string Name { get { return name; } }

    private readonly string address;
    public string Address { get { return address; } }

    public NameAndAddress(string name, string address)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

Then you can use:

```
Dictionary<string, NameAndAddress>
```

which makes it very clear what's going to be stored.

You could implement equality etc if you wanted to. Personally I would like to see this sort of thing made easier - anonymous types *nearly* do it, but then you can't name them...

Comment: Sealed, readonly, properties, ... - one of the most concise immutable examples I've seen.  But what about overriding Equals and GetHashCode? :)

Answer (score 7):

```
class A {
  public string X, Y;
}

Dictionary<string, A> data;
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a struct containing your values and then use

```
Dictionary<string, MyStruct> dict = new Dictionary<string, MyStruct>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary of KeyValuePairs

```
Dictionary<string,KeyValuePair<string,string>>
```

Comment: I don't like this idea, as although it *will* do what you want, it's misleading - why is the second string viewed as a key for the third?

Comment: Yes, you're right, but in some situations that is a fast and not so ugly solution...
Anyway a custom implementation, or the use of Tuple is probably the best in general (but Tuple is only in .net 4.0)

Comment: -1 This is very misleading. There is no logic in what should be a key and what should be a value in the KeyValuePair<string,string>

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is [exactly that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx). You can store your two values in a class or a structure. Or do you want something else?

Answer (score 0):

Make a class to hold your value and make it a Dictionary.  If the class is only used in the context of one containing class (e.g. it is used to deliver a data structure for a class property), you can make your class a private nested class.